# Why did switch work and if did not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question. My code works just fine, but I don't understand, why my if Statement didn't work?

Switch:

```
switch($('#radioo').html()) {

    case 'On':
        $('#hrflowo').html('Click button to turn HR Flow off')
                .append('<br/>')
                .append('<button id="radioo" style="padding:5px 30px 5px 30px; color:#fff;background-color:rgb(192,13,13);border:none;">Off</button>');
        $('#hrflow1').attr('src', 'assets/images/charts/enhance/radiology/hrflow-2.jpg');
        $('#hrflow3').attr('src', 'assets/images/charts/enhance/radiology/hrflow-4.jpg');
        break;

    case 'Off':
        $('#hrflowo').html('Click button to turn HR Flow on')
                .append('<br/>')
                .append('<button id="radioo" style="padding:5px 30px 5px 30px; color:#fff;background-color:rgb(192,13,13);border:none;">On</button>');
        $('#hrflow1').attr('src', 'assets/images/charts/enhance/radiology/hrflow-1.jpg');
        $('#hrflow3').attr('src', 'assets/images/charts/enhance/radiology/hrflow-3.jpg');
        break;
}
```

If Statement:

```
if($('#radioo').html('On')) {
    $('#hrflowo').html('Click button to turn HR Flow off')
            .append('<br/>')
            .append('<button id="radioo" style="padding:5px 30px 5px 30px; color:#fff;background-color:rgb(192,13,13);border:none;">Off</button>');
    $('#hrflow1').attr('src', 'assets/images/charts/enhance/radiology/hrflow-2.jpg');
    $('#hrflow3').attr('src', 'assets/images/charts/enhance/radiology/hrflow-4.jpg');
}
else if($('#radioo').html('Off')) {
    $('#hrflowo').html('Click button to turn HR Flow on')
            .append('<br/>')
            .append('<button id="radioo" style="padding:5px 30px 5px 30px; color:#fff;background-color:rgb(192,13,13);border:none;">On</button>');
    $('#hrflow1').attr('src', 'assets/images/charts/enhance/radiology/hrflow-1.jpg');
    $('#hrflow3').attr('src', 'assets/images/charts/enhance/radiology/hrflow-3.jpg');
}
```

Both were wrapped in a click event `$('#radioo').click(function(){`, but the if statement did not work. Can someone explain me why that is?

Best

Frederik

Comment: $('#radioo').html('On') will set value 'On' in radioo element. What are you trying to do in if condition?

Comment: Use `$('#radioo').html() == 'On'` in if condition instead of `$('#radioo').html('On')`

Comment: `$('#radioo').html('On')` does not resolve to `boolean`

Comment: you are not selecting anything with html('on')

Comment: Thanks... I didn't realize this in that moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `$.fn.html()` function!

**1. When using with one argument:**

If it was passed a value, like that in you IF STATSMENT:

```
$('#radioo').html('On');
```

It simply changes the document, set the tag content, then return a jQuery object.

**2. When using without any argument:**

If it was called without passing a value, like that in you SWITCH STATSMENT:

```
$('#radioo').html();
```

It simply returns the document content as a string.

---

So in your IF statsment, no matter how the tag content is, it returns the jQuery object, which absolutely was judged as true in the if condition.

Comment: I think he also really wants to use jQuery's `val()` instead of `html()`, as it would make much more sense to check the value of the radio.

Answer (score 0):

Your switch translates into `if($('#radioo').html()=='On')` instead of `if($('#radioo').html('On'))`

`.html(arg)` returns a jQuery object, with the purpose of allowing you to chain calls

Answer (score 0):

This will never work,

Whenever you pass argument to html function it will set the html rather than get the html element.

So your if loop should look like this:

```
if($('#radioo').html() == 'On'){
        $('#hrflowo').html('Click button to turn HR Flow off').append('<br/>').append('<button id="radioo" style="padding:5px 30px 5px 30px; color:#fff;background-color:rgb(192,13,13);border:none;">Off</button>');
        $('#hrflow1').attr('src', 'assets/images/charts/enhance/radiology/hrflow-2.jpg');
        $('#hrflow3').attr('src', 'assets/images/charts/enhance/radiology/hrflow-4.jpg');
        }
        else if($('#radioo').html() == 'Off'){
            $('#hrflowo').html('Click button to turn HR Flow on').append('<br/>').append('<button id="radioo" style="padding:5px 30px 5px 30px; color:#fff;background-color:rgb(192,13,13);border:none;">On</button>');
        $('#hrflow1').attr('src', 'assets/images/charts/enhance/radiology/hrflow-1.jpg');
        $('#hrflow3').attr('src', 'assets/images/charts/enhance/radiology/hrflow-3.jpg');
}
```